# How would i restrict the company table to only allow each companyID to 10 countries?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

This is my answer at this point, if this is correct can someone give a more in depth explanation
as I am trying to teach myself SQL/ or point out how wrong I am

```
CREATE TABLE locations(
companyID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (companyID Between 1 and 6),
countries CHAR(20),
primary key(countries),
FOREIGN KEY (companyID) REFERENCES company (companyID)
);
```

kind regards,
new SQL user.

PS. I understand i can use a check constraint or a check trigger but I am trying to do this in CREATE TABLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE TABLE locations(
companyID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (companyID Between 1 and 6), countries CHAR(20),
primary key(countries),
**CONSTRAINT 'locations_companyID_foreign'** FOREIGN KEY (companyID) REFERENCES company (companyID) **ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT**
);